# What are the meanings of "stochastically dependent" and "functionally dependent"?

Tags: experiment-design, mathematical-statistics

What are the meanings of "stochastically dependent" and "functionally dependent"? What is the difference? 
(I saw the usage of the above terms in the paper "[Maximum entropy sampling and optimal Bayesian experimental design](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/1467-9868.00225/abstract)")

Comment: I discuss such a distinction in a reply (to an unrelated question) at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/17148.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the intuition. Is there a place that I can find the formal definition?

Comment: "Stochastic" dependence is just the standard definition of lack of independence of probabilities or random variables; see almost any textbook on probability.  For a clear definition of functional dependence see the [second sentence here.](http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Ford/WFNewns.pdf)  For even more information, Google "functional dependence mathematics definition".

Comment: @whuber The link you have given is broken.

Comment: @Dilip That's a shame--one would expect a national organization like the MAA to manage its site better than that.  I searched their site and could not find that document again.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A$ and $B$ denote *Bernoulli* random variables representing the
inputs to an Exclusive-OR gate, and let the Bernoulli random variable
$C = A\oplus B = A + B \bmod 2$ represent the output of the Exclusive-OR
gate. We assume that the two inputs are functionally *independent* or *physically* independent random variables because the two input signals come from different circuits and we have no reason to believe that there is any *dependence* between them. We capture this notion in probability by insisting that $A$ and $B$ are *stochastically*  independent
random variables, that is, for $i,j \in \{0,1\}$
$$P(A = i, B = j) = P(A=i)P(B=j).\tag{1}$$  Now, the *output* of the 
Exclusive-OR gate is very much functionally *dependent* on its inputs. Notice that
$$P(C = 1) = P(A=1,B=0) + P(A=0,B=1).\tag{2}$$
Note also that 
\begin{align}
P(C=1,A=1) &= P(A=1,B=0) = P(A=1)P(B=0)\tag{3}\\
P(C=1,A=0) &= P(A=0,B=1) = P(A=0)P(B=1)\tag{4}\\
P(C=0,A=1) &= P(A=1,B=1) = P(A=1)P(B=1)\tag{5}\\
P(C=0,A=0) &= P(A=0,B=0) = P(A=0)P(B=0)\tag{6}
\end{align}

Now for the fun part.  $A$ and $B$ have been assumed to be independent Bernoulli) random variables already but now assume further that they both have parameter $\frac 12$. Then, from $(1)$ and $(2)$, we readily determine that $C$ also has parameter $\frac 12$. Furthermore, the right sides of $(3)$-$(6)$ have value $\frac 14 = P(C=i)P(A=j)$, that is,
$C$ and $A$ are *stochastically* independent random variables even though $C$ and $A$ are very much functionally *dependent* random variables. Similarly, $C$ and $B$ are stochastically independent but functionally dependent random variables. In fact, $A,B,C$ are an example of *pairwise*
independent random variables that are not mutually independent random variables.

> Functionally *independent* random variables are assumed to be stochastically independent random variables; indeed the notion of
>   the functional independence is the source of the assumption of stochastic independence. However, stochastic independence should not be assumed to imply functional independence; stochastically independent random variables could very well be functionally dependent.

Note that if in the example above we assume that independent Bernoulli
random variables $A$ and $B$ have
parameters distinct from $\frac 12$, then $C$ and $A$ are no longer
stochastically independent random variables. On the other hand, the
independence of $A$ and $B$ survives the departure from $\frac 12$ because that independence is based on the *functional* independence of $A$ and $B$.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, stochastic dependence among two random variables X, Y is just (given by) conditional distributions of Y given X and X given Y (similarly dependence of any two random events plus obvious generalizations of this problem). These conditional distributions are directly obtainable from a joint distribution of the random vector
(X, Y). The task to find the dependence is to find the joint distribution of (X, Y) which often may be a hard task. For some examples see the "parameter dependence method" for construction of the conditional distributions or see the concept of "weak [i.e., stochastic] dependence".

#### Edit

To my previous answer let me add what follows: When there is a functional (strong)  dependence of the variable Y on X any deterministic value x (when X = x) determines an exact deterministic  value y (Y = y) according to a functional rule y = f(x). When stochastic (weak) dependence of y on x takes place a particular value x does not exactly  determine a value y but instead affects probability (or probability density or hazard rate) of occuring the random event Y = y. Between others x affects the "probability of y" through affecting any parameter of G(y; A), where G( ) is a cdf and A is its parameter so that A becomes (deterministically) determined by x (A --> A(x) ). Thus through the assignment A --> A(x) we obtain the conditional distribution G*(y | x) = G*(y; A(x)). The latter describes the stochastic dependence of Y given X = x. For more see the "parameter dependence method".